# When differentiating a function with more than one variable, why do variables sometimes disappear or stay?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When finding the general solution of $$dy/dx=(x+y-2)^2$$ using $u = x + y - 2$, the first step would be to rearrange the latter equation so that $y = u - x + 2.$ Then taking the derivative of both sides would result in $$y'=u'-1.$$ Then $dy/dx$ can be substituted so that $u'-1 = (u)^2$, and then rearranged and solved with an integral.

*Why does taking the derivative of both sides of the second equation not result in $y'=-1$*? In earlier problems such as finding the derivative of a parabolic function $y=ax^2+bx+c$, our derivative was $y'=2ax+b$, with $c$ disappearing completely. Why isn't it $y'=2ax+a'x^2+b'x+b+c'\,$?

*When doing implicit differentiation, why wouldn't any $y$ values with a power of 1 disappear?* Why do they become $y'\,$? For a problem like $2x-y=-1$, why does taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$ result in $2-y'=0$ instead of $2=0\,$?

I am having trouble identifying when some variables disappear or gain the prime symbol when taking a derivative.

Comment: Maybe it would be more clear to write your differential equation as $y'(x) = (x + y(x) - 2)^2$, and to write $u$ as $u(x) = x + y(x) - 2$. So then $u'(x) = 1 + y'(x)$, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that you are taking the derivative *with respect to* some variable, so only that variable "disappears."

It may be helpful to think of this in terms of $\tfrac d{dx}$ notation. Then taking the derivative of $2x-y=-1$ gives $\tfrac{d}{dx}(2x-y)=\tfrac d{dx}(-1)\Rightarrow 2-\tfrac {dy}{dx}=0$, and you can then replace $\tfrac {dy}{dx}$ with $y'$ if you desire. The same reasoning applies to the first equation.

The key thing to keep in mind is which quantities are dependent on the variable you are taking the derivative with respect to. In the example $y=ax^2+bx+c$, $a,b,c$ are constant values which do not depend on $x$. If instead $a,b,c$ were *functions* of $x$ then in fact you would have $y'=2ax+a'x^2+b'x+b+c'$ (notice that if $a,b,c$ are constants than their derivative would be $0$, and you recover precisely $2ax+b$ on the right side.